# Override AvroIO default Coder in Dataflow

Tags: java, avro, google-cloud-dataflow, kryo, apache-beam

I'm trying to use a custom Coder for processing data in Dataflow. What I did is the following:

- Exported data from BigQuery to avro files
- Auto-generated a class from the schema in those files using avro-tools-1.7.7.jar
- Wrote a custom Coder for the class using Kryo
- Annotated the class with `@DefaultCoder(MyCustomCoder.class)`
- Registered my coder using    `p.getCoderRegistry().registerCoder(MyCustomClass.class,    MyCustomCoder.class);`
- Read data from the avro files using `PCollection<MyCustomClass> pc =    p.apply(AvroIO.Read.named("Name").from("gs://bucket/path/to/*.avro").withSchema(MyCustomClass.class));`

The thing is, if I have a bug in my Coder, my job only fails during a shuffling step. It doesn't look like Dataflow is using my custom Coder for loading the data from the avro files. 
Is that really the case? And if so, is there a way to override the Coder used for loading the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AvroIO currently always uses the built-in AvroCoder for reading from input files.  You can change the coder later in the pipeline like you describe.  If your data is not actually encoded in a way that AvroIO can read, you should use a different source instead, for example, a new subclass of [FileBasedSource](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/FileBasedSource.java).

Comment: AvroCoder reads the data fine, but it's quite slow compared to Spark. Does AvroCoder use the default Java serialization? Because in Spark I use Kryo.

Comment: AvroCoder uses Avro serialization, which is significantly faster the default Java serialization.  However, it's certainly possible Kryo is even faster.